# Change Middleman CSS Directory

Tags: import, sass, middleman, bourbon

I'm having a one problems with my Middleman site. I have two questions I haven't been able to figure out:

1. How do I move the "all.css.scss" file that my "index.html.erb" file
   is referencing to the "Sass" folder? Of course, the link breaks when I move
   it. Can't seem to find where to update the pathway in the code. Is this something I could do in bash?

Files are on [my github](https://github.com/carolanncan/My-Middleman-Site).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing/setting 'css_dir' within 'config.rb'?
See http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/configuration/#toc_2 for general information.

Comment: I had tried that and it returned an error after restarting the Middleman server. But I _italic_think_italic_ I've successfully changed my directory now as it's not returning an error.

However, now, none of my stylesheets are being recognized when the html loads. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. I'm not sure what I was doing incorrectly the first few times, but I tried one more time updating the file path in config.rb and `stlyesheet_link_tag`... That fixed everything.

It did create a new issue of any background images in my css not loading. But the directory issues is completely resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to change a setting is to use `set` in your `config.rb` file.

```
#config.rb

set :js_dir, 'javascripts'
set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'
set :fonts_dir, 'assets/fonts'
set :images_dir, 'assets/images'

etc...
```

You can also use a newer syntax which is used for most of the global settings in Middleman.

```
#config.rb

config[:js_dir] = 'javascripts'
config[:css_dir] = 'stylesheets'

etc...
```

[Middleman Docs](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/configuration/#changing-settings)